# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'

Tags: python, pycharm, scikit-image

I have already installed my scikit-image on my following path:
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image

I have installed it from interpreter in PyCharm

However, whenever I run the following

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import register_translation
from skimage.feature.register_translation import _upsampled_dft
```

It keeps returning error as below :

```
ImportError: No module named skimage

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import register_translation
from skimage.feature.register_translation import _upsampled_dft
from scipy.ndimage import fourier_shift

image = data.camera()
shift = (-22.4, 13.32)
# The shift corresponds to the pixel offset relative to the reference image
offset_image = fourier_shift(np.fft.fftn(image), shift)
offset_image = np.fft.ifftn(offset_image)
print("Known offset (y, x): {}".format(shift))

# pixel precision first
shift, error, diffphase = register_translation(image, offset_image)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)

ax1.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax1.set_title('Reference image')

ax2.imshow(offset_image.real, cmap='gray')
ax2.set_axis_off()
ax2.set_title('Offset image')

# Show the output of a cross-correlation to show what the algorithm is
# doing behind the scenes
image_product = np.fft.fft2(image) * np.fft.fft2(offset_image).conj()
cc_image = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(image_product))
ax3.imshow(cc_image.real)
ax3.set_axis_off()
ax3.set_title("Cross-correlation")

plt.show()
```

What would be the cause of this import failure?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PyCharm, I think that you have to check if you've installed the package in the same environment that you're working on.

Comment: yes i have installed anyway i have just solved my error